# Block Content Tag Not Working In Django When Inheriting From Base.html

Tags: python, django

I have seen other questions like this but none of them solve my issue.

I have been using Django for a while and i have been exploring the block content part now. But i have run into a problem. The base.html looks like this:

[image]

and my home.html looks like this:

[image]

as per the internet the home.html page should have hello and replaced text. But I only see hello in the page

[image]

it would be amazing if you would be able to help me on this as soon as possible.   :)

Comment: Can you share the view that renders the home.html template?

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item


def home(response):
    return render(response, "main/base.html", {})

Comment: You’re rendering the base template and not the home template?

Comment: Ok Thanks Really Fixes The Problem. And can you please post this as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Please share the view function which renders the html template